# Why SQL Server Express 2008 install requires Visual Studio 2008 in checklist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When installing SQL Server Express Edition 2008, checklist says

"Previous version of Visual Studio 2008"

and asked me to upgrade to sp1. Unfortunately sp1 for some reason refuses to install on my brand new pc (Windows 7).

So why can't I just bypass this ? Why would SQL Server Express needs VS2008 to install that's insane.

SQL Server install used to be as easy as 123, now it has become a nightmare like installing Oracle.

Will I have to go back to Windows XP ?

Comment: Management Studio is a version of Visual Studio. Is there an option to install without Management Studio? Also 1) what issue are you getting trying to install SP1 and 2) This should be migrated to superuser.

Comment: @Martin - yes, there is. You can also get the version of SSE that does not include tools at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Sql Server Management Studio is built upon the Visual Studio standalone Shell.

You will find that if you choose not to install the SSMS this requirement will vanish, but this is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you won't need Visual Studio 2008 in order to install SQL Server. This can be caused by some previous versions that you had installed, beside the SSMS problem. Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139) for required actions before installing SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree that SQL Server 2008 install is probably the worst SQL install ever.

Having said that, 2008 R2 is out now, perhaps the new management studio is built on VS2010? Alternatively, don't install Management studio and use something else like VS2008, or VS2010 express to access the database.

Comment: database managment is next to nil in VS. That would be a very bad choice.